# How do I sort by a hidden column in DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

When I apply DataTables to the following:

```
<td class="years"><?php $years."-years" ?></td>
<td class="..." ...
... other <td> ...
```

my table displays as follows:

```
10-years ... ... ...
10-years ... ... ...
5-years  ... ... ...
7-years  ... ... ...
9-years  ... ... ...
```

because of the alphabetic ordering. I need `10-years` to appear at the bottom. To do that I added `<td class="hidden"><?php $years ?></td>` right after `<td class="years"><?php $years."-years" ?></td>` and added `"order": [ 1, 'asc' ]` to the datatable initialization:

```
$(".table-rates").DataTable( {
   "order": [ 1, 'asc' ]
});
```

after which it stopped working and started reporting an error in the console: "Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined".

Can someone explain how I can sort by a hidden column in my DataTables? I looked up online, but the solutions did not work for me. Even worse, the syntax is extremely confusing and hard to follow. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add error you get?

Comment: "Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's unnecessary to add other column, you can use [data-attributes](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) of datatable, add in your html code `data-order`:

```
<td class="years" data-order="<?php $years ?>"><?php $years."-years" ?></td>
```

And your code JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "order": [ 0, 'asc' ]
    });
});
```

**Result:** https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/69/

Comment: This works like a charm. I must upote the solution.